# Parse variables from json url using jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, parsing

How I can parse parameters like "city" from json?

I have url like this: http://api.db-ip.com/addrinfo?addr=8.8.8.8&api_key=key, this return me this:

```
{
    "address":"8.8.8.8",
    "country":"US",
    "stateprov":"California",
    "city":"Mountain View"
}
```

I want to apply city (or country) variable to `<input type>`, to show visitors some info about location.

Comment: is `db-ip.com` your domain or is it an external resource?

Comment: Can you check what errors are there in the console (F12). If I'm correct, there should be an error saying that you can't do cross-domain AJAX. `db-ip` doesn't seem to have CORS nor JSONP.

Comment: Yes, I get this error: is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load that JSON object and access the "city" field, use jQuery's `getJSON` method to get a native JS object in response.

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.db-ip.com/addrinfo?addr=8.8.8.8&api_key=key", function(data) {
   // do something with data.city;
});
```

However, in your case, you're trying to make a cross-domain JSON request -- not allowed. Since db-ip.com doesn't allow it, you'll have to proxy the request using PHP.

Set up "dbip.php" on your server as a proxy (cf. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Then you just load JSON from dbip.php on your own server, which queries db-ip.com for you. The browser is happy because the AJAX request it makes doesn't cross domain names.

Comment: I'm trying to get city value from this json in to input field (for form).

Comment: Does your input field have a specific ID? e.g. <input id="city"/> If so, you'd just do something like $('#city').val(data.city) inside that function block.

Comment: Yes, I've trying this:
`
<input type="text" id="city"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON( "http://api.db-ip.com/addrinfo?addr=8.8.8.8&api_key=key", function(data) {

$('#city').val(data.city);
});
</script>
`

Comment: But can't get value city.

Comment: I just noticed the comment above (that you're loading cross-domain AJAX). You can't make a direct JSON request from another domain. JSONP is a simple cross-browser solution (loading a script tag that contains the desired response, wrapped in a call to your chosen method) if there was a supported JSONP endpoint at db-ip.

Comment: Do you control your own server? A crude solution, if db-ip.com doesn't provide a JSONP API option, is to proxy calls to them through your own server-side code (and thus make the call via the same domain). They provide a PHP client out of the box; if you could run PHP on your own server, then you could make the calls that way.

Comment: Yes, I have own server. But as I thunk, their php solution is too heavy to use it just to get some geoip in form. But their db is very accurate. How I can proxy call, maybe somu guide on the web? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Basically, you just need to call their server THROUGH your own server. That way, your getJSON call goes to your own server, where you're allowed to just load straight JSON. This article explains it: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get it to work. Trying several variants of "proxy", but always get nothing as result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var response={
 "address":"8.8.8.8",
 "country":"US",
 "stateprov":"California",
 "city":"Mountain View"
};
$("#city").val(response.city);
```

Comment: Cool, but how I can get 'responce' from url?

Comment: if url return type is json ,you can get that with ajax.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can to this?

Comment: i think you are running html on file system. you should try localhost or web.

Comment: No, I run this from running web server. I mean, your example works perfect. But in my case (using dp-ip.com) I have cross-domain issue.